# Question about some specific differences between new T() and new T in C++11 and afterwards

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

***Attention please***: you may think this post is a duplicate to [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new). But the said post was ***more than 12 years*** ago and none of the answers ***mentions the C++11 and afterwards***.

***And what's more***, my question is about the comment of the answer which has most votes and my question is about the detailed code snippet below.

As per the comment of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/620402/13611002), which says that[emphasise mine]:

> With C++11 you can do this in stack too; B obj{}; will make the object value-initialized (to 0s) as opposed to B obj; which will be default-initialized (***garbage***).

But it seems that there is no difference between them for [this code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/7z3x4Krvb).
Tips: Pay attention to the outputs of the said code snippet.

`new Line()` is default-initialized but it's not ***garbage*** indeed.

Here is the aforementioned code snippet:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
struct Point {
    T x;
    T y;
};

struct Line{
    Point<double> head;
    Point<double> tail;
    double *demo;
    int color;
    //std::string comment;
};

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point<T>& point) 
{
    os << "(" << point.x <<"," << point.y <<")";
    return os;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Line& line) 
{
    os << "head: " <<  line.head << std::endl;
    os << "head: " <<  line.tail << std::endl;
    os << "demo="  << static_cast<void*>(line.demo) << std::endl;
    os << "color="  << line.color << std::endl;
    //os << "string=" << line.comment << std::endl;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    auto ptr2lineWithBracket = new Line();
    std::cout << *ptr2lineWithBracket;

    std::cout << "==================" << std::endl;
    auto ptr2lineWithout = new Line;
    std::cout << *ptr2lineWithout;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
head: (0,0)
head: (0,0)
demo=0
color=0
==================
head: (0,0)
head: (0,0)
demo=0
color=0
```

Comment: `new Line()` is [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) and `new Line` is [default initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization)

Comment: @Ch3steR It seems a mess, there are so many rules. **It's hard to understand and to remember**. How do you think about it?

Comment: *but it's not garbage* How do you know that the zeros are not garbage?

Comment: `new Line()` is [zero initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) since C++11.

Comment: @273K As per the said link,* These(i.e. `T{}`,`T()` and etc) are examples of other types of initializations, which **might** perform zero initialization.* You see it's `might` other than `must` or `always`.

Comment: @273K Since C++03, actually.

Comment: @John: Not being zero-initialized is not the same as being default-initialized. Calling a constructor is not considered zero-initialization, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question about some specific differences between new T() and new T

`new T()` is value initialisation. For aggregate classes such as `Line` and `Point<T>` this means that all sub objects are value initialised. For primitive objects such as `double*` and `int` this means zero initialisation.

`new T` is default initialisation.  For aggregate classes such as `Line` and `Point<T>` this means that all sub objects are default initialised. For primitive objects such as `double*` and `int` this means **no** initialisation. If an object isn't initialised<sup>1</sup>, then it has an indeterminate value. This means that their value is indeterminate. If a program reads an indeterminate value (of a type other than narrow character type), then the behaviour of the program is **undefined**. This is to be avoided. Don't do this.

The example program reads indeterminate values, and its behaviour is undefined.

> in C++11 and afterwards

There hasn't been a change regarding these since C++03 where value initialisation was added to the language.

Not related to the example directly, but a new syntax was added for value initialisation in C++11:`new T {}` (in addition to analogous syntaxes using curly braces for temporary and variable initialisation).

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that objects with static storage duration are zero initialised before any other initialisation regardless of the syntax you use.